# Type deduction only template

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have a function template defined like this :

```
// #1
template <typename R, typename T>
R func(T arg) { ... }

// #2
template <typename T>
T func(T arg) { ... }
```

I would like the type T to be always deducted by the compiler so that :

```
func<int>(my_var); // calls #1
func(my_var); // calls #2
```

When trying to do the first call, I get an ambiguous function call error.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: I believe here the problem would be if the type of `arg` is the same as the return type, how will the compiler know if #1 or #2 should be called? Hence, we have an ambiguous pair of functions.

Comment: #2 type shouldn't be defined by the user and should always be deducted.
#1 R type needs to be defined by the user.

Meaning that func<int> shouldn't be used to call #2.

Comment: One possibility would be to prohibit type specification for #2, if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't get any award for elegance, but...

```
// #1
template <typename R, typename T>
R func(T) { /* ... */ }

// #2
template <int = 0, typename T>
T func(T) { /* ... */ }
```

Calling `func<int>(4)` would try to provide a type argument to the non-type parameter of `#2`, so it is SFINAE'd away.
Calling the function with implicit deduction uses the default argument and still works fine.